# What does this operator '>>' and '//' mean?

Tags: python

I'm not sure what this means: total = n - (n >> 1)
(I don't understand what the '>>' does)

I'm not sure what this means: partition = n // kth
(I don't understand what the '//' does)

Comment: You should pay a little effort to look at the Python official documentation or thousands of tutorials on Google.

Answer (score 0):

`>>` is the [bitwise-shift](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) operator. Variables are represented at the machine level in bits. It literally shifts the bits to the right or left and substitute zeros in their place.

`//` is [floor division](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/floor_division.html). Floor division rounds off the number